# Quran with original manuscript evidence

Tags: quran

I need a link to a webpage or book that lists Ayaat (verses) and the earliest manuscripts available that contain those Ayaat.

For example, the first literary evidence we have of Surah Fatihah is the Sana'a manuscript in Yemen (dated to the early first century).

Is there anything like this in existence?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because asking for Book references was decided not to allow in this site. Read [More...](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/questions/261/what-is-our-stance-on-book-recommendations?s=1|0.9904)

Answer (score 1):

I found a an article talking about "[Kufic script](http://jafrianews.com/2014/12/01/worlds-oldest-qurans-manusript-available-is-written-by-imam-ali-a-s/)" and they claim it to be the world's oldest manuscript of Qur'an right after 20 to 40 years after the death of Prophet Muhammad (pbuh).

May the creator guide us all.

Answer (score 1):

The Corpus Coranicum is an ongoing research project aimed at collecting all the oldest manuscripts of the Qur'an. You can read about it here:
http://www.coranica.de/corpus-coranicum-en

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here [topkapi manuscripts](https://www.islamic-awareness.org/quran/text/mss/topkapi.html). It is dated to the late 1st century / early 2nd century of hijra. Only 2 folios are missing and it is said to have 99% of the Qur'an. It lists it in a table just as you requested.

Hope this helps.